# Hortonworks schema registry cluster mode

Tags: schema, apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform

[image]I'm using Hortonworks schema registry with NIFI and things are working fine. I have installed Hortonworks schema registry on a single node and I'm afraid if that machine goes down what will happen to my NIFI flows. I have seen in Hortonworks schema registry architecture that we can use mysql, PostgreSql and In-Memory storage for storing schema. AFAIK none of them are distributed system. Is there any way to achieve cluster mode for high availability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do active-active or active-passive replication for MySQL and Postgres, but that is left up to you to implement, as Hortonworks will likely forward you to the respective documentation on each tool, and that is the reason why the documentation for these tools doesn't guide you towards these design decisions in itself, as you should be aware of the drawbacks when having a SPoF

The Schema Registry itself is just a web-app, so you could put it behing your favorite reverse proxy, or within a container orchestrator, such as Docker support in HDP 3.x